# compiler isn't issue error/warning in mismatch function parameter

Tags: c, static-analysis, coverity

I have the next code :

test.c

```
#include "a1.h"


int main() {
    int a = 8;
    foo(a);
    return a;
}
```

a1.h

```
void foo (int  a);
```

a1.c

```
int f = 0;

void foo (int  a, int b){
    f=5+a+b;
    return;
}
```

Pay attention that in a1.c foo has 1 more parameter than the prototype defined in a1.h.
The compiler isn't issue a warning or an error and so as coverity :

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/a1.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/a1.d" -MT"src/a1.d" -o "src/a1.o" "../src/a1.c"
Finished building: ../src/a1.c

Building file: ../src/test.c
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/test.d" -MT"src/test.d" -o "src/test.o" "../src/test.c"
Finished building: ../src/test.c

Building target: test
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
gcc  -o "test"  ./src/a1.o ./src/test.o   
Finished building target: test
```

How can I defend myself in those cases ? I know that if I will add #include "a1.h" in the a1.c file I will get an error but is there a way to get an error without the "include " ?

Comment: Do you get a linker error finally?

Comment: How you are invoking the compiler/linker here?  You should definitely be getting a linker error about an undefined function.

Comment: Also this isn't something to be detected by SCA.

Comment: You have `using namespace std;` your file name is `a1.c` it is C not C++, and beside that, you did not include any C++ header where you might need namespace std.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler isn't issuing a warning because it does not know that `foo(int)` from `a1.h` header and `foo(int,int)` from `a1.c` file is the same function. C++ allows functions to be *overloaded*, so both functions could potentially coexist. That is why C++ compiler cannot detect this problem, so you need to wait until the linking stage.

If you were compiling using C, not C++, you could have the compiler detect this condition simply by including `a1.h` at the top of `a1.c` file.

Answer (score 0):

You're overloading `foo`. The version with only one parameter is never defined, hence you should get a linker error when using it.

> How can I defend myself in those cases ?

You can't defend yourself from function overloading. Just make sure that you've got the same signature in both the header as the source file.